# Check if specific object is empty in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to check if an object is empty?

ex:

```
private brand: Brand = new Brand();
```

I tried:

```
if (this.brand) {
  console.log('is empty');   
}
```

not working.

Comment: you want to check if brand is an empty object without properties or if it is undefined?

Comment: Maybe it's not working because your condition tests whether this.brand is NOT empty :) Either try if(!this.brand), or do console.log('is not empty')

Comment: @adiga I want to check if the properties of this object are empty.

Comment: @Unfra can you share your Brand class?

Answer (score 200):

Use `Object.keys(obj).length` to check if it is empty.

**Output**  : 3

**Source:** [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: @Unfra can you please mark this is the right answer? Thanks!

Comment: But if you wanted to move this into a helpful function, we don't know the types of the object to safely check it

Answer (score 50):

You can use `Object.keys` like this:

```js
class Brand { }
const brand = new Brand();

if (Object.keys(brand).length === 0) {
  console.log("No properties")
}
```

If you want to check if the object has at least one *non-null*, *non-undefined* property:

- Get all the values of the object in an array using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)
- Check if at least one of has value using [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const hasValues = 
    (obj) => Object.values(obj).some(v => v !== null && typeof v !== "undefined")

class Brand { }
const brand = new Brand();

if (hasValues(brand)) {
  console.log("This won't be logged")
}

brand.name = null;

if (hasValues(brand)) {
  console.log("Still no")
}

brand.name = "Nike";

if (hasValues(brand)) {
  console.log("This object has some non-null, non-undefined properties")
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Here is a comparison between the 2 most popular answers, they do have slightly different implications:

```js
let o1 = {}
console.log(JSON.stringify(o1) === '{}')
console.log(Object.keys(o1).length === 0)
// true
// true

let o2 = { p: undefined }
console.log(JSON.stringify(o2) === '{}')
console.log(Object.keys(o2).length === 0)
// true
// false

let o3 = { l: null }
console.log(JSON.stringify(o3) === '{}')
console.log(Object.keys(o3).length === 0)
// false
// false
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also use [**lodash**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) for checking the object

```
if(_.isEmpty(this.brand)){
    console.log("brand is empty")
}
```

Comment: Embedding lodash for a js-native functionality feels overkill.

Comment: @Mozgor Lodash makes code more readable, that's the main usecase of it. Whole lodash functionality can be replaced with vanilla JS if you like wasting your time :)

Comment: @DurkoMatko there is a big difference between using lodash for deep equality - which would take several lines to recode at very least - and for a basic "is empty" check.

There is also a difference between embedding lodash for this same basic and native function vs using isEmpty in a project already intensively using lodash.

Answer (score 10):

```
Object.keys(myObject).length == 0
```

A Map obj can be created with empty properties and size might not work .
Object might not be equal to empty or undefined

But with above code you can find whether an object is really empty or not

Answer (score 9):

```
let contacts = {};
if(Object.keys(contacts).length==0){
      console.log("contacts is an Empty Object");
}else{
      console.log("contacts is Not an Empty Object");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is the fastest construct that I'm aware of, albeit it uses somewhat puzzling [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop that doesn't loop (in my tests it's about 2x faster than [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys))

```
export function isObjectEmpty(object: Record<string, unknown>): boolean {
  for (const property in object) {
    // if any enumerable property is found object is not empty
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Careful about `Object.keys` and `Array.some` solutions, in case if your object is not even initialized and worth `null`.

Also care that there is no key worthing `undefined`.

```js
const objNotInitialized = null;

console.log(Object.keys(objNotInitialized));
```

---

You could add an extra check in that case, leading to the final soluce :

```js
function isEmpty(obj) {
  return !obj || !Object.keys(obj).some(x => obj[x] !== void 0);
}

console.log(isEmpty({
  x: void 0,
}));

console.log(isEmpty(null));

console.log(isEmpty({
  key: 'value',
}));
```

---

If you can use `Object.values` :

```js
function isEmpty(obj) {
  return !obj || !Object.values(obj).some(x => x !== void 0);
}

console.log(isEmpty({
  x: void 0,
}));

console.log(isEmpty(null));

console.log(isEmpty({
  key: 'value',
}));
```

---

```js
const obj = {};

// Using Object.keys to loop on the object keys and count them up
if (!Object.keys(obj).length) {
  console.log('#1 obj is empty');
}

// What if a key worth undefined ?
const objWithUndefinedKey = {
  x: void 0,
};

// Using Object.keys is not enough, we have to check the value behind to remove
// undefined values
if (!Object.keys(objWithUndefinedKey).some(x => objWithUndefinedKey[x] !== void 0)) {
  console.log('#2 obj is empty');
}

// Or more elegant using Object.values
if (!Object.values(objWithUndefinedKey).some(x => x !== void 0)) {
  console.log('#3 obj is empty');
}

// Alternative is to use for ... in
let empty = true;

for (key in objWithUndefinedKey) {
  if (objWithUndefinedKey[key] !== void 0) {
    empty = false;
  }
}

if (empty) {
  console.log('#4 obj is empty');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
JSON.stringify(this.brand) === '{}'
```

Comment: this is a lot slower than the Object aproach

Answer (score 0):

`Object.values(this.brand).some(b => b != null);`

Answer (score 0):

The good approach is to have a short function that you can use everywhere in your app :

```
export const isEmpty = (obj) => {
return obj === null || undefined
    ? true
    : (() => {
            for (const prop in obj) {
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        })();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you build ECMA 7+ can try
`Object.entries(obj).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fully type-safe answer for this, that allows you to tell  `tsc` that an object is, or is not empty when narrowing a union type, you can create a type guard utility function using one of the above answers as suits your needs:

```
const isEmpty = (obj: unknown): obj is Record<never, never> => 
  typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null && Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
```

This allows you to have a type that could be an object with keys or an empty object (or any other type for that matter), and tell `tsc` that it is (or is not) and empty object by:

- Checking whether the passed argument is an object
- Checking that it's not `null` (`typeof x === 'object'` returns `true` for null)
- Running any other checks that suit your use cases (depending on whether you care about null or undefined values within the object) - in this case the `Object.keys().length` method.

You can then use this with:

```
const unknownType: {prop: number} | Record<never, never> =
  functionThatCouldReturnAnEmptyObjectOrNot();

// Type guard returns 'true' and 'definitelyEmpty' will be inferred as an empty object
const definitelyEmpty = isEmpty(unknownType) ? unknownType : {};

// Type guard returns 'false', reversed with the '!', and 'definitelyNotEmpty'
// will be inferred as an object of type {prop: number}
const definitelyNotEmpty = !isEmpty(unknownType) ? unknownType : {prop: 1};

// Not using a type guard, tsc will still infer 'notNarrowed' as 
// ({prop: number} | Record<never, never>), meaning that using it where an empty 
// object (or not empty object) is required will cause a warning.
const notNarrowed = Object.keys(unknownType).length === 0 ? unknownType : {};
```

Some other potentially useful notes:

- `Record<never, never>` means an empty object (`{}`)
- `{}` as a type annotation (e.g: `const empty: {} = {}`) actually means 'any non-nullish value' so is only just above `any` in terms of type safety, and will allow most other values (`const empty: {} = 3` would be valid).

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using type-fest's `EmptyObject`, I went with this typeguard:

`is.emptyObject(val)`

https://github.com/sindresorhus/is#emptyobjectvalue

> Returns true if the value is an Object and Object.keys(value).length
> is 0.
>
> Please note that Object.keys returns only own enumerable properties.
> Hence something like this can happen:

```
const object1 = {};

Object.defineProperty(object1, 'property1', {
    value: 42,
    writable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true
});

is.emptyObject(object1);
//=> true
```